# Roboguice ViewInjection in custiom views.

Tags: android, android-fragments, roboguice

I have a problem:

I create fragment and than add it to activity with TranactionManager.replace()

```
public class Main extends RoboActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root, new     BaseFragment()).commit();
    }
}


public class BaseFragment extends RoboFragment {
    @InjectView(R.id.text)
    TextView textView;
    @InjectView(R.id.viewWithViews)
    ViewWithViews viewWithViews;
    public BaseFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       //text view and viewWithViews injected there
    }
}
```

A this point all ok FragmentView created and all views are injected.

But next:

```
public class ViewWithViews extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.child_text)
    TextView textView;
    private View button;

    @Inject
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public ViewWithViews(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
       onFinishInflate();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.child_view, this);
    }

    public ViewWithViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
    }

    public ViewWithViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate(); // sharedPreferences are injected!
        this.button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        this.button.setOnClickListener(this);
        RoboGuice.injectMembers(getContext(), this); //force injection
        //still no views injected there

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println(view); // all possible events are passed, manual click. "textView" is not injected
    }
}
```

No views are injected in ViewWithViews!

However if put Fragment directly in MainActivity R.layout.activity_main all view injections are performed! I'm bit dissapointed. Is it a bug, or I'm doing it wrong?

*org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0-alpha-2*

*android sdk 19*

Answer (score 0):

In onFinishInflate call:

```
RoboGuice.getInjector(context).injectViewMembers(this);
```

injectMembers only calls the guice Injected objects, not android views.

Answer (score 0):

**getSupportFragmentManager**().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment, new ReaderFragment(), "fragment").commit();